# Как пробросить порт докер контейнера на локаль?

Tags: golang, docker

Создаю вот такой контейнер

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

WORKDIR "/srv"

COPY --chown=1000 build /srv/bin

EXPOSE 8080

USER 1000
CMD ["/srv/bin/service"]
```

/srv/bin/service работает на порту 8080 и изнутри контейнера прекрасно запускается через этот порт. Но пробросить на локальную машину этот же порт не могу. Запускаю вот так: **docker run --rm --name container-name *-p 8080:8080* image** захожу на http://localhost:8080/ и у меня  [ошибка доступа](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhc2p.png)

Comment: windows, небось? тогда разбирайтесь с файерволами-антивирусами-и-прочими-вредными-программами.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема оказалась в самом сервисе собранном на голенге, а именно в следующем коде.

```go
    router := chi.NewRouter()
    router.Get("/", func(writer gohttp.ResponseWriter, request *gohttp.Request) {
        writer.Write([]byte("Hello World!"))
    })

    httpServer := &http.Server{
        Handler:           router,
        ReadHeaderTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        Addr:              "localhost:8080",
    }

    if err := httpServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        zap.L().Fatal("listen", zap.Error(err))
    }
```

После рефакторинга кода все заработало

```go
    router := chi.NewRouter()
    router.Get("/", func(writer gohttp.ResponseWriter, request *gohttp.Request) {
        writer.Write([]byte("Hello World!"))
    })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router); err != nil {
        zap.L().Fatal("listen", zap.Error(err))
    }
```

Буду признателен если кто то пояснит почему так происходит.

Comment: между `localhost:8080` и `:8080` - большая разница. В первом случае подключения ожидаются только на localhost, То есть, подключится извне не получится. А вот второй случай позволяет подключение с разных интерфейсов. Есть подозрение, что докер при пробросе порта наружу использует как раз не локалхост (это достаточно логично). И тогда все стает на свои места.

Comment: Спасибо, сразу все стало ясно.